# How to find whether the copied content is from word or text document or browser web page?

Tags: javascript, regex, ms-word, paste

I need to process the pasted content in my code based on , from where the content is copied. If the content is copied from word, then I need to do some functionality. In the same way , another function has to be invoked when content is copied from text document  and another function for browser content. We will get the html content through clipboard data.

1. To check whether it is copied from word , I have used the regex `/class="?Mso|style="[^ ]*\bmso-/i`.

But here the problem is while a part of the content is copied from word it doesn't have class Mso and only have styles mso. In some cases , it has only Mso class names and not styles. Even though the condition has OR , the regex fails when any one of the Mso is present in html content. So I need to check whether the html content is copied from word with a common regex for both cases.

2. Need a regex to check whether the html content copied is from text document or browser web page.

Regex used for checking content copied from word.

```
RegExp= /class="?Mso|style="[^ ]*\bmso-/i
```

While copying from browser web page I get the below HTML format.

```
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><span style="box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(17, 17, 17); font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.25px; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: pre-wrap; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif;">We have checked the sample  </span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Whereas, the text copied from text document will be the plain HTML without body tags or fragment.  I need to remove these start and end fragments of html content from browser page.

I need a regex to check whether content is copied from text document or browser web page.

Comment: Do you mean you just need to remove all text between `<!--StartFragment-->` and `<!--EndFragment-->`? `s.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->[\s\S]*?<!--EndFragment-->/g, '')`?

Comment: No. I need to retrieve the html content alone without these fragments. Only content from browser web page has fragments so I need to check whether the content is plain text or it has  fragments

Comment: Isn't it the same? Remove X from AXYXZ to get AYZ.

Comment: Yes, but the above code replace everything between body as empty string

Comment: Then `s.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->([\s\S]*?)<!--EndFragment-->/g, '$1')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep all the text between two tags, `<!--StartFragment-->` and `<!--EndFragment-->`.

While you could use

```
s = s.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->([\s\S]*?)<!--EndFragment-->/g, '$1');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wOqki2/1)

I'd advise to unwrap the lazy dot pattern and use a more efficient pattern like:

```
s = s.replace(/<!--StartFragment-->([^<]*(?:<(?!!--(?:Start|End)Fragment-->)[^<]*)*)<!--EndFragment-->/g, '$1');
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wOqki2/3)

The non-nested `<!--StartFragment-->` and `<!--EndFragment-->` will get removed and all between them will be put back into the resulting string.

Group 1 (`$1`) pattern is `[^<]*(?:<(?!!--(?:Start|End)Fragment-->)[^<]*)*`:

- `[^<]*` - 0 or more chars other than `<`
- `(?:<(?!!--(?:Start|End)Fragment-->)[^<]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `<(?!!--(?:Start|End)Fragment-->)` -  a `<` not followed with `!--`, either `Start` or `End`, and then `Fragment-->`
  - `[^<]*` - 0 or more chars other than `<`

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. This worked for me. Do you have any idea on why the below regex fails when the html has only mso class name in styles or class name in element directly. RegExp= /class="?Mso|style="[^ ]*\bmso-/i

Comment: @keerthana See [what it matches](https://regex101.com/r/9szWwv/1). What are your failed test cases?

Comment: My content has bold tag with style "mso" but the regex shows no matches  
     https://regex101.com/r/awb3EH/1

Comment: @keerthana See a different demo with [just 2 changes](https://regex101.com/r/awb3EH/2).